# Sending to a Datagram socket, without blocking indefinitely

Tags: linux, sockets, haskell, nonblocking, datagram

We have some code to send metrics to a `SOCK_DGRAM` where another daemon listens and aggregates/proxies these messages. Opening the socket looks like:

```
sock <- socket
(ai :: AddressInfo Inet Datagram UDP):_ <- getAddressInfo (Just "127.0.0.1") Nothing aiNumericHost
connect s (socketAddress ai) { port }
return sock
```

And at the moment we write to it like:

```
send sock payload mempty
```

I want to ensure the call above doesn't block for very long (or at the very least doesn't block indefinitely), but my understanding of unix sockets is not very deep and I'm having trouble understanding how exactly `send` blocks, looking at internals [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/socket-0.8.0.1/docs/src/System-Socket-Unsafe.html#unsafeSend) and [here](https://github.com/lpeterse/haskell-socket/blob/bade04065eaadc1a701d2b67cd928ec289226fd9/platform/linux/src/System/Socket/Internal/Platform.hsc).

There is a related question here that was helpful: [When a non-blocking send() only transfers partial data, can we assume it would return EWOULDBLOCK the next call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391208/when-a-non-blocking-send-only-transfers-partial-data-can-we-assume-it-would-r)

So my questions specifically are:

- General socket question: I see in this implementation `send` is going to block (after busy-waiting) until there is room in the buffer. How exactly is this buffer related to the consumer? Does this mean `send` may block indefinitely if our `listen`-ing daemon is slow or stalls?
- If I would rather abort and never block, do I need to make my own fork of `System.Socket.Unsafe`, or am I missing something?

I'm only concerned with linux here.

**EDIT**: Also, and what probably got me started with all of this is I find that when the metrics collector is not running, that every other of my `send` calls above throws a "connection refused" exception. So why that is, or whether it's normal is another question I have.

**EDIT2**: Here's a complete example illustrating the connection refused issue if anyone would like to help repro:

```
import Data.Functor
import System.Socket
import System.Socket.Family.Inet

repro :: IO ()
repro = do
  let port = 6565
  (s :: Socket Inet Datagram UDP) <- socket
  (ai :: AddressInfo Inet Datagram UDP):_ <- getAddressInfo (Just "127.0.0.1") Nothing aiNumericHost
  connect s (socketAddress ai) { port }

  putStrLn "Starting send"
  void $ send s "FOO" mempty
  void $ send s "BAR" mempty
  putStrLn "done"
```

I'm using `socket-0.5.3.0`.

**EDIT3**: this seems to be due to the `connect` call, somehow. (Testing on `sockets` latest):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, OverloadedStrings, NamedFieldPuns #-}
import Data.Functor
import System.Socket
import System.Socket.Protocol.UDP
import System.Socket.Type.Datagram
import System.Socket.Family.Inet

repro :: IO ()
repro = do
  (s :: Socket Inet Datagram UDP) <- socket

  -- Uncommenting raises eConnectionRefused, everytime:
  -- connect s (SocketAddressInet  inetLoopback  6565     :: SocketAddress Inet)
  putStrLn "Starting send"
  void $ sendTo s "FOO" mempty (SocketAddressInet  inetLoopback  6565     :: SocketAddress Inet)
  void $ sendTo s "BAR" mempty (SocketAddressInet  inetLoopback  6565     :: SocketAddress Inet)
  putStrLn "done"
```

As I understand it we should be able to use `connect` (at least the underlying syscall) to set the default send address. I haven't dug into the implementation of `connect` in the library yet.

I've opened this: https://github.com/lpeterse/haskell-socket/issues/55

Comment: STREAM and DGRAM sockets work very differently. A DGRAM socket doesn't know nor care if anything is actually listening on the other side. It just fires whatever you pass to it into interstellar space.

Comment: It looks like the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag to `send` is likely relevant. The Haskell interface passes the flags through, and presumably defines the constants somewhere. But my understanding of these things is probably shallower than yours.

Comment: A `DGRAM`  socket doesn't block a send. It just dumps a packet onto the network, and if the receiver's buffer is full then the packet is discarded. There is no connection, so nothing to block on.

Comment: Maybe there's something peculiar happening then... when the metric collector (which I'm running with `docker`; perhaps that's part of the issue) is not running I get "connection refused" exceptions for every other send in my application, when testing in ghci

Comment: @n.m. do you have any ideas re. edit?

Comment: @jberryman You cannot possibly get 'connection refused' with UDP. You must be using TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a Haskell issue -- it's expected behavior on Linux when sending two UDP packets to a localhost port with no listening process.  The following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

int main()
{
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in dstaddr = { AF_INET, htons(6565), {htonl(0x7f000001)} };
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) &dstaddr, sizeof(dstaddr)))
        perror("connect");
    if (send(s, "FOO", 3, 0) == -1)
        perror("first send");
    if (send(s, "BAR", 3, 0) == -1)
        perror("second send");
    return 0;
}
```

will print `second send: Connection refused`, assuming nothing is listening on localhost port 6565.

If you do any one of the following -- (i) send to a non-local host, (ii) drop the `connect` call and replace the `send`s with `sendto`s, or (iii) send packets to a port with a process listening for UDP packets -- then you won't get the error.

The behavior is a little complex and not well documented anywhere, though the manpages for `udp(7)` hint at it.

You may find the discussion [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231270/econnrefused-errors-on-udp-sendto) helpful.

Comment: Awesome thanks, would you say this is what's happening: the second `send` call is failing early with the asynchronous error from the first call (and so the third call doesn't raise an error, but the fourth call will, and so on...)? I've come across this guide now, which I'll be consulting for these kinds of questions from now on: http://www.masterraghu.com/subjects/np/introduction/unix_network_programming_v1.3/ch08lev1sec11.html

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct:  the first call actually sends a UDP packet and returns success.  Internally, this generates an ICMP unreachable error which the second call reports *instead* of sending a UDP packet, so the third call can send a UDP packet and repeat the process.  Because this is the loopback interface, it's entirely reliable -- send, error, send, error.  On a real network interface, you'd see something similar but less predictably.